# What could cause water to leak from the top of the fridge?

Tags: kitchens

It appears that once a day, there is some water streaming from the top of the fridge (on the inside). I collect about a small cup of water nearly every day that comes out from roughly the same spot (it then turns into ice if I don't pour it out fast enough). The fridge seems to work "fine" otherwise. This seems to have started when I made the temperature in the fridge (Kenmore) a bit colder. What could be the cause of it?

Comment: Is it near the automatic ice maker?

Comment: Does it have an ice maker and/or water faucet?

Comment: there is no icemaker in the fridge.

Answer (score 4):

The drain line that usually leads from under the condensor coils to a pan under the fridge may have frozen solid when you turned the temp down. That'd let water accumulate between freezer and fridge compartments. Try defrosting w doors open for a few hours. That should clear the tube.

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a good idea, I will definitely give defrosting a try once I have a chance, will update the question/thread afterwords.

Answer (score 4):

Is your freezer on top?  We had the same issue. Like Wayfaring Stranger said, the drain in the freezer was clogged. To fix it, turn off the unit, empty the freezer and use hot water to unfreeze the drain plug. It can also clog with debris and for that I used an air compressor to blast it out.