# How can I stop my fridge from collecting water?

Tags: refrigerator

We have a Kenmore fridge (15 years old) with the freezer on top. The freezer is having a problem where the drain (I presume for when it defrosts) keeps filling with ice and then the entire bottom of the freezer fills with ice and begins dripping water into the fridge below. ([similar to this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/29760/what-could-cause-water-to-leak-from-the-top-of-the-fridge)) We have defrosted and cleared the drain and the problem persists. We are to the point were we need to deice the drain nearly every week or water starts to drain to the fridge section. What are we missing for a more permanent solution?

Comment: Freezer defrost no longer working?

Comment: It sounds like your drain is still clogged.

Comment: We defrost the drain, and it drains ok, and then freezes up again fairly quickly. We validate that the drain is running, by putting hot water down it without issue.